# create a subdomain for a virtuoso installation

Tags: subdomain, amazon-route53, virtuoso

We have a Virtuoso installation on an AWS VM, working on default `port 8890`, that we would like to create a subdomain, e.g., `rdf.example.com:8890`. The problem is that the guy that is responsible for the subdomains created a record on the service we use (don't know which), but it is not working.
Is there something that needs to be done in order for virtuoso to work under a subdomain?

I used the AWS's Route53, with no luck as well.

Answer (score -1):

Seems you want to setup a [multi-homing](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/qsmultihome/) setup for hosting multiple subdomains on the same Virtuoso instance, which Virtuoso supports as in the link above.

Failing that I would suggest posting your question on the [OpenLink Community Forum](https://community.openlinksw.com), to get more expert responses ...

Comment: I will give that a better read, but from a first look, it doesnt seem to be what I need. the doc you posted, seems to me, that will create a second domain on the machine running virtuoso. Thats not what I need. I need to create a dns url that directs to the actual virtuoso. I will check it again later to make sure i got it right. thanks anyway